# The first else part is not reading

Tags: asp.net

```
public partial class StudentView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
        {
            string str = "Mysqlqeury";

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                da.Fill(ds, str);
                GDStudents.DataSource = ds;
                GDStudents.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                string myStringVariable1 = "No Student Record(s) Exist!! ";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myAlert", "alert('" + myStringVariable1 + "');", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string myStringVariable = "Enter Student Id Or Student Name!";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myAlert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);
        }
        con.Close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: text box value is string or int

Comment: Could you put slightly more effort into writing your question?

Comment: What scenario are you testing? You have to be a bit more specific here. What do you mean by 1st else?

Comment: This question is in need of vast improvement. What is it that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page.IsPostBack will always be true in this case it will only be false on first page load. Because this condition is within a button click event handler Page.IsPostBack will never be false so the else portion will never get executed.

Here is some documentation on Page.IsPostBack property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

You only should use Page.IsPostBack if you need to execute code on first page load.

What Exactly are you trying to test here?

If you wanted to just test if any records were in the database then just check if the DataSet you're returning is empty. Try something like this:

```
public partial class StudentView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);

    bool IsDataSetEmpty(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
        {
          if (table.Rows.Count != 0) 
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
        {
            string str = "Mysqlqeury";

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, str);
            if (!IsDataSetEmpty(ds))
            {
               GDStudents.DataSource = ds;
               GDStudents.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
               string myStringVariable1 = "No Student Record(s) Exist!! ";
               ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myAlert", "alert('" + myStringVariable1 + "');", true);
            }
    }
    else
    {
        string myStringVariable = "Enter Student Id Or Student Name!";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myAlert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);
    }
    con.Close();
}   
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an alternative solution to achieve your desired result. Please mark this as an answer if it helps. Thanks and Good luck. @Sugu

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first else will not be called for any of the following reasons:

- `TextBox1.Text` does not have any value
- `Page.IsPostBack` is true
- some kind of exception occurs

Try to check for those, you might find the answer.

Comment: Why IsPostBack true? There is no IsPostBack conditional in the else part of the statement...
Also as it's on a button click I would think it's always going to be a postback